# Hover on a card with clickable links

Tags: design-patterns, hover, cards, microinteractions

I am working on card which has a clickable link/ clickable options but the card itself is not clickable. I want to add a shadow to the card when someone is hovering on/ clicking on the link. I have read in many posts that only when something is clickable, we should put a hover action on. Does it seem like a good interaction pattern?
[image: No Hover and Hoverable Card]

Answer (score 2):

Certainly seems misleading to me. We highlight the interactive element when hovered by a pointer to provide visual feedback as to what the user is trying to interact with. Highlighting the entire card seems to imply the entire card will be activated as a single element.